# Screen "Must be connected to a Terminal."

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, tty

I'm on a Debian OS.

I'm trying to use screen under a SSH session. But when I'm trying to run the command

```
screen
```

the shell answer me :

```
Must be connected to a Terminal.
```

If I enter

```
tty
```

it answer me :

```
Not a tty
```

I don't know why and I try

```
ssh -t login@server
```

it doesn't work..

Please help me I really need this !

Thanks

EDIT :

I read [this topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/21806/how-can-i-launch-a-screen-session-with-a-command-over-ssh-on-a-remote-server-fro) but it still doesn't work

Comment: Google found this http://serverfault.com/questions/21806/how-can-i-launch-a-screen-session-with-a-command-over-ssh-on-a-remote-server-fro

Comment: I already read it and it didn't worked for me :(

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. If you get this error while in a chroot, here is what helped me:

(run these commands from outside the chroot)

```bash
$ sudo mount -o bind /dev /home/chroot/dev
$ sudo mount -t proc proc /home/chroot/proc
$ sudo mount -t devpts devpts /home/chroot/dev/pts
```

`/home/chroot` being the path to your chroot. Update above commands accordingly.

source: http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=23583#post128768
(see also http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-433006-start-0.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
getty tty
```

...and then relaunch:

```
screen
```

If you don't have getty, you could try installing it:

```
apt-get install getty
```